# ErrorDocument Not Working As Local Path inside httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: apache, http

**I have tried other posts, but they aren't working for me.**

I am using Apache 2.4.

I am trying to make an ErrorDocument load for when it receives a 403 error, but for some reason, it doesn't load the page and just gives a different error.

**site.com/folder:**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

**site-error.log:**

```
[Sun Oct 20 09:51:00.018294 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 2692:tid 1272] [client no.ip.here.anymore:42204] AH01276: Cannot serve directory C:/Apache24/docs/site/folder/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

**httpd-vhosts:**

```
<directory "${SRVROOT}/docs/">
    Require all granted 
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /docs/error/403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /docs/error/404.php
</directory>
```

I have tried putting 'AllowOverride All' above.

The ErrorDocument loads successfully when I use a URL (**ErrorDocument 403 site.com/error/403.php**), but I cannot use a URL and need to be able to use a local path.

The DocumentRoot is **"${SRVROOT}/htdocs"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Alias and surely it worked, I forgot the double / after C: and so the first time I did it I don't think it got the proper path.

```
Alias "/error" "C://Apache24/docs/error"

<directory "${SRVROOT}/docs">
    Require all granted 
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
</directory>
```